How can I manually group features with the SHAP package?
I would like to apply SHAP to calculate feature importance for an RNN model that predicts an output variable y [N_instances x 1] from a feature matrix [N_instances x N_times x N_features]. As a concrete example, imaging that each instance comes from collecting a time series of temperature and pressure from a chemical reactor each hour for 12 hours, and using it to predict the total mass of some chemical produced during the reactor run. In this case, N_features = 2 (temp and pressure). When I try to do this, I can only get shap values for temperature/pressure at individual times (i.e. I get 2 x 12 shap values). I'd like to get an overall shap value for temperature/pressure (i.e only 2 shap values).
As far as I can tell, SHAP requires a model function and a 2-D array of features. My RNN model is meant to take in 3-d data. So, I have to do some array reshaping. This is what I have so far:

#Imports
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import shap
import numpy as np

# Generate random 3-D X data and 1-D y data.
N_TIMES = 10
N_INSTANCES = 256
N_FEATURES = 3
X = np.random.random((N_INSTANCES, N_TIMES, N_FEATURES))
y = np.random.random((N_INSTANCES, 1))

#Write a simple model
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(N_TIMES, N_FEATURES), return_sequences = False, stateful=False, activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1))

# Compile and train the model on data
model1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])
history = model1.fit(X,
                     y,
                     batch_size=16,
                     epochs=3,
                     verbose = 0
                    )
# Define function to take in a 2D feature array and return model predictions
def model_for_shap(X_flat):
    X = X_flat.reshape((X_flat.shape[0], N_TIMES, N_FEATURES))
    return model1.predict(X)
X_flat = X.reshape((N_INSTANCES, N_TIMES*N_FEATURES))

# Run SHAP 
background = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]*X.shape[2]))
e = shap.Explainer(model_for_shap, background)
shap_values = e.shap_values(X[:10].reshape((10, N_TIMES*N_FEATURES)))
print(shap_values.shape)


The final print outputs:
Shape of shap_values: (10, 30)

This is sensible - I asked for the shap values for 10 datapoints, and there are N_TIMES x N_FEATURES = 30 total features.
What I would like to be able to get is shap values resulting from masking out the entirety of each features time series at a time. So, I'd get shap values for 3 features (N_FEATURES) instead of 30 (N_FEATURES x N_TIMES).
Is this possible? I thought the Partition masker might help, but I can't figure out how to manipulate the clustering argument to accomplish my goal.
